# How do I get a SELECT date query to run on my SQL database from C# application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
string dateType = DateFieldDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
string DateField1 = DateTextBox.Text;
string DateField2 = dateSelection2Text.Text;
DateField1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateField1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateField2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateField2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string DateFiled = "DateFiled";

if (dateType == "DateFiled")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateFiled",  TypeCode.String, DateFiled));
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));

  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE @DateFiled BETWEEN @DateField1 AND @DateField2";
   SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
   GridView1.DataBind();
```

I'm not sure anyone can help without seeing the database behind, but I thought I'd give it a shot.  So I'm querying my database, trying to get records within a certain date range out. No errors thrown, just no results, despite there being associated data behind which should be pulled in.  I've tested the SQL query on the database in a SQL editor using the dates rather than the parameter variables and gotten the correct results. I think it may need a CAST in order to be able to check the date in the string to the datetime in the database?  But when I try putting that in 
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE @DateFiled BETWEEN CAST(@DateField1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateField2 AS DATE)";
I get an error saying Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Print the actual values being passed to your sql query, most likely there is something in the string format causing an issue.

Comment: Your query is a bit of an issue. You have DateFiled in your where predicate, but that looks like it should be a column. As posted you are getting rows where one date literal is between two other date literals. Meaning you will get either all the rows or no rows. You might also take a peek at this. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: For the `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` datatypes the format `xxxx-xx-xx` is culture sensitive, and could either be interpreted as `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM`, this is why you get a conversion error. This would not matter of course if you passed your parameters as dates, rather than converting them from a string, to a date, then back to a string.... Also, your `WHERE` clause is essentially something like `WHERE 'DateFiled' BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01', this is why you are not getting any rows.

Comment: `WHERE @DateFiled BETWEEN @DateField1 AND @DateField2` <----- 

If you're trying to selectively pick which date field to compare your range against, this approach isn't going to work.

Comment: I'm trying to look at the column DateFiled in my database and compare the values in that column to the two dates which are inputs from my application.

Comment: I got it to work using Gareth's suggestion regarding the input.  The CAST worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string dateType = DateFieldDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
 string DateField1 = DateTextBox.Text;
 string DateField2 = dateSelection2Text.Text;
 if (dateType == "DateFiled")
 {  
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
   SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));

   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN CAST(@DateField1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateField2 AS DATE)";
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I needed the CAST in place to get the date lookup in the SQL database to work correctly but as Gareth said, it showed a conversion error.  By not changing the format to yyyy-MM-dd, and using the CAST, it worked correctly.  I also needed to remove DateFiled as a parameter as it should have just been in the SQL statement as a column name after the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a string "column name" to the stored-procedure.  Inside the stored procedure, the resulting SQL would look something like this:

**SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE 'DateFiled' BETWEEN '6/1/2017' AND '6/8/2017'**

...Which will not have the effect you are trying for...

You'll need to try something like this:

```
if (dateType == "DateFiled")
{
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));

  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN @DateField1 AND @DateField2";
   SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
else {
   //some other Date
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));

  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE SomeOtherDate BETWEEN @DateField1 AND @DateField2";
   SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you hard-coded the variable DateFiled as 'DateFiled', you don't need to pass it in as a parameter.

Just do:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dateCorrection WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN @DateField1 AND @DateField2";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
GridView1.DataBind();
```